# when defining functions in python program crashes

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions, raw-input

as apparent by my obvious lack of programming experience im fairly new and a slow learner can someone please explain this to me? the rest of the program runs fine independent from this section but i can't even run this section by itself.
I have four functions to declare and define.x is an the position of the character r is the row number and c is the collumn number.

```
def go_north():
    x = r - 1 
def go_south():
    x = r + 1
def go_west():
    x = c - 1
def go_east():
    x = c + 1

collumn = "c"
row= "r"

x = []
y = 0 
row =3
collumn =9
while (y < row):
    x.append ([])
    y= y +1

y = 0 
z = 0 
while(z < row): 
    y=0
    while(y < collumn): 
            x[z].append('*')
            y=y+1
    z=z+1
x[4][4] = "#"


raw_input ("")
    if "w" = go_north:
    else "s"= go_west:
    else "a"= go_east:
    elif "d"= go_west:

for y in x:
    print y
```

raw_input("")

when i run any part of this code the program crashes and i cant find my problem.
any tips or places that i can go to to find the solution? (as silly as it may seem the indenting is correct in the actual program)

Comment: If it "crashes", it will give you an error message. Part of learning to program is learning to read the error messages. Try and do so, and see if you can solve the problem yourself; if you really can't, update your post with the error and what you have done, and maybe we can guide you.

Comment: I don't even know where to start.

Comment: What did you want it to do?

Comment: There are so many problems in your code that I would suggest reading a book on Python first.

Comment: Hint:  Check colon usage and indenting.

Comment: Your go_north function has a colon : after the name. The other function definitions need that too.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot wrong here...

```
def go_north():
    x = r - 1 

def go_south():
    x = r + 1

def go_west():
    x = c - 1

def go_east():
    x = c + 1

input = raw_input ("")
if input == "w":
    go_north()
elif input == "s":
    go_west()
elif input == "a":
    go_east()
elif input == "d":
    go_west()
```

I'd suggest reading up on python syntax

Comment: Yeah, a little more work will need to be done, but without knowing the goal of the program, this is the best I could do

Comment: Pointing out that it they are pointless would have been one way to do ;-)

Comment: yeah sorry guys its mostly to move a character around in an array by changing row and column location